# Efficient way to sort string List by order defined in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string List by an order defined in another array. I know it's possible in a variety of ways, but I'm not sure how to do it efficiently. I need this to be able to handle a large unsorted list, with thousands of items. Here's what I came up with:

```
List<string> sortStringListByArray(List<string> unsortedList, string[] order)
{
     List<string> sortedList = new List<string>();
     for(int i = 0; i < order.Length; i++)
     {
          foreach(string s in unsortedList)
          {
              if(s.Equals(order[i]))
              {
                  sortedList.Add(s);
              }
          }
     }
     return sortedList;
}
```

It works as expected, but it's definitely not efficient. Is there any way I can do this without iterating across both the list and the order?

Edit: Clarification

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "efficient"? What type of **measurement** you refer to? Time? Lines of code? Memory? Furthermore are you sure that code will affect that measurement **significantly**? In other words: are you sure you gain much when optimizing the code above? Beware: [premature optimzation is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: I did mean efficiency by time, though now that you say it, I'm honestly not sure if it's necessary to optimize time-wise. This is intended to be run on lists of fairly large size (10000+), so I was thinking it would be important to do it efficiently.

Comment: Just measure before doing any unnneccessary optimization, as they will make your program more complex and thus harder to maintain. Just use a `StopWatch` and measure how long it takes to run that code. If it´s only a few nano-seconds, why bother for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to represent it is with right inner join :

```
return order.Join(unsortedList, a => a, b => b, (a, b) => b).ToList();
```

---

The best time complexity is O(n+m) using Lookup or Dictionary :

```
var lookup = unsortedList.ToLookup(x => x);

return order.SelectMany(x => lookup[x]).ToList();
```

The above can be few times faster by using `Dictionary<string, int>` to get the counts of the items in `unsortedList`, and then looping over `order` to generate the result based on the corresponding values in the counts Dictionary.

---

`Lookup` and `Dictionary` use [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store values. To find an item in a hash table, a hash value is calculated from the value, which is similar to estimated location/index of where the value is in the hash table. This allows for only 1 or few comparisons needed to find (or not) a value in a hash table. So, O(n) to generate the Lookup or Dictionary from `unsortedList`, and because hash table has average O(1) lookup time, only O(m) time needed to generate the result using Lookup or Dictionary, resulting in total O(n+m) time complexity.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Would you mind explaining why a Lookup is better? I haven't learned how to use them.

Comment: somewhat, I understand that it reduces complexity by mapping values, but I don't know much more than that.

Comment: The `ToLookup` basically builds a dictionary of lists of strings, keyed on the unsorted strings, grouping all duplicates in individual entries of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments, you can simply sort your list by the index of it in the `order` array:

```
 List<string> sortedList = unsortedList.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(order, x));
```

Comment: This doesn't account for duplicates in the list, which is what I need. I should've clarified that, my bad.

Comment: @MattWaterman you mean you want to keep order in `order` array but eliminate the duplicates?

Comment: No, I want to sort the List in a specific order, defined in the order array. For example, the order could be {"c","d","b","a"} and the list of {a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d} would become {c,c,d,d,b,b,a,a}

Comment: Hmm, this would still have O(kn) time complexity where k is the size of order, and n the size of the unsorted strings, doesn't it? Or even worse, O(knlogn).

Comment: yes, as @RobertBaron mentioned this will have worse time complexity than the O(n*m) that OP has

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ashkan's answer, you can do `order.Distinct().ToList()`, which removes duplicates. Since order is already sorted, you can just process then return it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an efficient sorting algorithm using the array index as the ordering input. This would be more efficient than your example solution.

E.g.,

```cs
List<string> sortStringListByArray(List<string> unsortedList, string[] order)
{
    var orders = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < order.Length; i++)
        orders[order[i]] = i;

     return unsortedList
         .OrderBy(s => orders[s])
         .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Same solution as @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani with time complexity worse than original problem.

Comment: Not anymore. Updated.